# ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have java web app which use Oracle db. 
Web app use hibernate.
I have 2 oracle instance - first one in server, second one in local virtual linux machine.

When I connect to local oracle instance at some point I get

> ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

exception. But when I connected to oracle (which is in server)  don't get that exception. I am doing exactly same action and dump is same. So I think problem in oracle. 
maybe some configuration are different.

Can anybody tell me what can be differences between oracle servers which leads to this situation?

UPDATE. some parts from stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000
```

Comment: the problem starts when you connect to oracle to second machine?

Comment: @Moudiz No when I do some specific action in web application.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what kind of query (HQL *and* generated SQL) really generates this issue

Comment: Probably your application is dynamically generating SQL based on the data, and thus when the data is not same in both the environments, it is highly likely that the generated SQL is different.

Comment: I am almost sure that the data also same. (
but thank you for comment I will double check this.

Answer (score 5):

> ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

This limit is not only applicable to **tables** and **views**, but also on the **temporary inline view** and the temporary internal **memory tables** which Oracle creates while executing a subquery.

For example,

Oracle creates a temporary inline view based on the **merge select**, thus the same restriction is implemented on this temporary inline view. So, you need to make sure that the number of columns in a **sub-select** or **subquery** also doesn't exceed this limit of `1000`.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection:

The above error indicates that you are trying to create a **collection** which exceeds the limit of **number of columns** allowed, i.e. the total number of columns exceeds `1000`.

Comment: the code is exactly same and when I connect to oracle which on server I do not get excpetion.

Comment: @user1321466 The application might be generating a database object based on the data, so probably data is not the same in both your environments.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this Exception and to skip the check of this limit, you can set a _fix_control parameter,
like:

ALTER SESSION SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF'

or

ALTER SYSTEM SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF'

(works with Oracle 12.1.0.2 Standard and Enterprise)